# How to differentiate a music and voice in a video file using FFMPEG?

Tags: video, music, ffmpeg, voice-recognition

This question may already have an answer here:

How to separate voice and background music from a video file 3 answers
No, my question is different. I will edit to explain how.
I have a movie.mp4 file, I extracted the audio from the video file using FFMPEG (ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:a pcm_s16le audio.wav).

Now from the audio file I can get the waveform, is there any way that I can differentiate the music and the voice from the audio file in the waveform and is it a best way to differentiate? I need the start time and the end time of the music from the extracted audio file.

So, at the end I might be getting multiple or single music file from the audio file.

Answer (score 0):

I had seen your question earlier today, and was working on another project.

I have not tested this yet, but audacity has a filter to attempt to remove vocals, or isolate vocals.  I have difficulty taking a picture, but the menu structure would be:

1. select the entire audio track
2. Choose menus  "Effect" -> "Plug-in 1 to 15" -> "Vocal Reduction and Isolation"
3. In the effect window there are some parameters which can be set, and a drop-down allows you to choose vocal reduction or isolation, and a few other options.

My reading about this (a google search) indicate that it works well in specific circumstances - for example if the vocals are on two tracks, and all instruments or other sounds are split between two tracks.

There is a second filter, "Vocal Remover" in the Plug-in 16 to 17" menu, which may also work.